# How to get submenu horizontal and centered under its parent?

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, submenu

First of all apologies for a question that has been asked many times- I did go through, I think, all the questions in stackoverflow and lots of other resources online, and after a few days testing and changing and adjusting- I still can't work out what is it that I'm doing wrong with my css, that I can't get the submenu horizontal and centered under its parent..?

Here's the link with HTML & my custom CSS

http://cssdesk.com/r7gZf

I'm using a Wordpress theme, and the theme's navigation CSS is in the link below, in case I missed something there that's creating the problem.

http://cssdesk.com/Th9E9

Will massively appreciate the help- I'm going mad.. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above is an interesting approach but the first li is not aligned with the child ul

You can try something like this: [CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/yL8jG)

Or another solution is to remove the absolute position of your sub ul and adding a div to fake the main ul box shadow:

**HTML:**

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item menu-item-28"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/restaurant/">RESTAURANT</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu left">
                <li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-138"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/restaurant/menu/">Menu</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/restaurant/restaurant-opening-times/">Opening Times</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/restaurant/restaurant-gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/restaurant/restaurant-contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item menu-item-25"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/bar/">BAR</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu center">
                <li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/bar/events/">What’s On</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/bar/bar-opening-times/">Opening Times</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/bar/bar-gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/bar/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item menu-item-27"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/party-bookings/">PARTY BOOKINGS</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu right">
                <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://51stokescroft.com.gridhosted.co.uk/party-bookings/contact-us-2/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
.main-navigation .bar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}

.main-navigation > ul > .menu-parent-item > a::before {
  content: none;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: visible;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat:repeat;

}

.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: relative;
}


.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Lusitana;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.75em
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f4e9e1;
  padding: 0.75em 2em;
  line-height: 1;
  position:relative;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > a {
  color: #3c2415;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > a {
  color: #3c2415;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.main-navigation li:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;

}
.main-navigation li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.main-navigation li ul {
  display: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul.right {
  margin-left: -25%;
}

.main-navigation ul ul.left {
  margin-left: -100%;
}


.main-navigation ul ul.center {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lusitana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #3c2415;
  padding: 0.75em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: none;
  box-sizing: none;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #3c2415;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.scheme-black .main-navigation > ul > li:hover > a {
  text-shadow: none;
}
.scheme-black .main-navigation .sub-menu li, .scheme-black .main-navigation .sub-menu .sub-menu li {
  background: transparent;
}
.scheme-black .main-navigation .sub-menu li:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both your and Szymon's corrections solve the centering problem- I'll read into them and will understand them- thanks a lot! How could I also get the submenu horizontal?

Comment: I've edited my answer to display it as a sub menu horizontally. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for getting back- checked on cssdesk- it is horizontal- yay- but it's centered according to the menu, and not submenu's parent item.. does that make sense? 
BUT.. I entered it all to my website and it doesn't do what it's doing on cssdesk - I think something might be overriden by the original theme's css which I'm not addressing? In cssdesk link below I added your latest codes & the theme's css underneath your css, starting with /* =Navigation - and there you can see what's happening on the website? =/ sorry for being a problem! :}
http://cssdesk.com/zPCUr

Comment: There is no clean way to do that -to my knowledges- as you are absolute to the parent and need to adapt your position to it, and as the number of child and the size of the parent vary. It's only possible with classes on the parent like in this edited version

Comment: Ahhh it works! It works!!! Thank you so so so so much, for your time and effort, you've saved my sanity, I would have never got that.. Just need to work out and learn what it is you did there! :) 
I'm still not quite sure how this site works, but think I can't 'upvote' you until I have 15reputation. When one day I have that I'll be back here to upvote you. Thanks again, I can't really express my gratitude! :)

Answer (score 0):

You had problem with your ul li ul li a width
I made it working [EXAMPLE](http://cssdesk.com/YC6Yj)

```
    .main-navigation ul ul a { 
       text-align: center;
       font-family: Lusitana;
       font-size: 12px; 
       font-size: 1.2rem; 
       color: #3c2415;
       width: 80px;        //added  
       padding: 10px 0;    //added
       -webkit-box-sizing: none; 
       -moz-box-sizing: none; 
       box-sizing: none;
       white-space: nowrap;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both your and Thomas's corrections solve the centering problem- I'll read into them and will understand them- thanks a lot! How could I also get the submenu horizontal? T